# Search Results Visibly Scrolling Underneath the Status Bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

When performing a search on a dataset via a `UISearchBar`, the search results successfully display in the `UITableViewController`'s `UITableView`. However, when scrolling down through the results, the `UITableView`'s rows visibly appear underneath the `UINavigationBar` and the simulator's status bar.

[image: Scrolling through search results]

This obviously is not the look that I'm going for. Ideally, I would like the `UISearchBar` to act as the `UITableView`'s header with all search results being contained below the `UISearchBar`'s scope buttons, but my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Below is the Storyboard setup of the relevant `UITableViewController` and its `UITableView`'s properties.

[image: Search results table view controller and its table view's properties]

Below is the relevant code that I am using to setup the `UISearchController` and its `UISearchBar`.

*BallotTunesSearchTableViewController.h*

```
@interface BallotTunesSearchTableViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate>
```

*BallotTunesSearchTableViewController.m*

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Initialize the search controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;

    // Setup the search bar
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:SongScopeName, ArtistScopeName, AlbumScopeName, nil];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

**Update**: Note that the `UITableViewController` is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, and when setting the translucence of the `UINavigationBar` to `NO`, the `UISearchBar` slides off the view along with the `UINavigationBar`.

[image: Search bar disappears]

Also note that I am not implementing the `UISearchBar` in Storyboard (however, I may take that route if I can't get my current setup to work).

Comment: Try setting the nav bar to not be translucent.

    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

Comment: @MikeWelsh Great suggestion. However when turning off the translucence of the `UINavigationBar`, the `UISearchBar` rolls off the view when selected because it relies on being embedded in the `UINavigationBar`.

Comment: Is this VC embedded in a UINavigationController? How are you presenting this search VC?

Comment: @MikeWelsh Yes, the above TVC is embedded in a `UINavigationController`, and at the moment, the app opens directly to that `UINavigationController` upon launch, presenting the above TVC as the first view.

Comment: If the navigation bar is not translucent and you haven't set the nav bar to hidden (`self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;`), I think it should be appearing... Not really sure what's going on for your situation. Have you tried implementing `preferredStatusBarStyle`?

Comment: I tried different statusBarStyles with no luck. :/

Comment: Note that I am not using a `UISearchBar` Storyboard element. However, I am considering taking that route to check if that solves anything.

Comment: You should embedded `searchBar` in your `UITableViewController` rather than `UINavigationController`.Otherwise, when you scroll tableView, the `searchBar` is over the `tableView` .

Comment: @Wongzigii My `UISearchBar` should be embedded in the header of my search result's `UITableView` via this line `self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;`. This line should keep my `UISearchBar` constantly at the top of my `UITableView` (even when scrolling), but it does not.

Comment: you mean you set up a `searchController` with a `searchBar` and placed the searchController as the `tableView` 's headerView in the `UITableViewController`?

Comment: @Wongzigii Correct. The `viewDidLoad` code above is what I'm using within my `UITableViewController`.

Comment: If you need to set up a searchBar, you should set it up by declare a property of UISearchBar in your header file,rather than using a UISearchBarController. Then place it into your UITableView's headerView.That may works.Actually, in iOS 8, you should use `UISearchController` class which contains a searchBar and a tableView.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several face palms, it all came down to the lack of this line of code:

```
self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Setting the presentation context to `YES` indicates that the view controller's view should be covered when the view controller presents the `UISearchController`.

Comment: Some extra notes, you have to add self.definesPresentationContext = true in the presenting view controller. For me, it didn't work if the presenting view controller had its status bar hidden, I had to make it visible as in the search result view controller